# Unzip downloaded gzipped content on the fly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, gzip

I am downloading a gzipped CSV with python, and I would like to write it to disk diretly as csv.

I tried several variations of the following:

```
url ='blabla.s3....csv.gz'
filename = 'my.csv'

compressed = requests.get(url).content
data = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed)
with open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(data)
```

but I am getting various errors - I am not sure I am passing the right part of the response to the gzip method. If anyone has experience with this, input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `zlib` to decompress the response.

```
import zlib

res = requests.get(url)
data = zlib.decompress(res.content, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)
```

---

Now, write to a file:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```